# How do I find empty markdown headings with regex?

Tags: regex, go

```
#    
## Good
##
```

I am trying to use regex to tell me when a markdown heading is empty. I use headings 1- 4. 
I've tried a lot of options, this is the most recent. 
It needs to see each heading (1-4) then mark if there is no text after. I was able to get this far looking at regex101.

```
(#{1,6}[[:space:]]{1,2})
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Can you give an example of input data and output data derived from them?

Comment: Added the go tag. Using a linter . https://github.com/errata-ai/vale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question right I think the following should do it:

```
#{1,4}[\s]*$
```

Breaking down each term in the regular expression:

- `#{1,4}` - matches between one and four # characters
- `[\s]*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `$` - this is the important one, this matches the end of the line.

So in English we have: between one and four # characters, followed by zero or more whitespace characters, and then the end of the line.

Comment: I marked this as an answer because the regex is technically correct. But in the tool I'm using Vale it doesn't matter work. It flags every header as empty. Text or not. My fault for not mentioning the tool in my initial question..

Comment: Oh, that sucks.  I'm not familiar with this Vale tool but it sounds suspect if the above regex is matching on populated header lines?